# Как можно универсально изменять состояние React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть код:

```
const handleChangeSellMax = (evt) => {
        this.setState({
            sellMax: evt.target.value
        })
    };
```

Таких повторяющихся кусков с разным полем для изменения состояния у меня множество. Как я могу написать одну функцию, в которую буду передавать название поля, которое нужно изменить и его значение, чтобы не плодить множество одинаковых методов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, можно просто передавать имя св-ва, как параметр функции

```
handleChangeStateProp(name, value) {
  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  });
}

// Где-то в render
// Не будем спорить о стрелочных функциях в обработчиках
<input onChange={e => handleChangeStateProp('name', e.target.value)} />
```

Можно сделать функцию, которая будет возвращать другую функцию для изменения конкретного поля. Если хочется какой-то большей семантики

```
createStatePropChangeFn = (name) =>
  value => this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });

// Где-то дальше в коде
// Этот обработчик можно вешать на события, отписываться от них и т. д.
this.handleChangeAge = this.createStatePropChangeFn('age');
```